# Не понимаю, с чего начать реализацию простого FOV

Tags: c++, разработка-игр

Вот есть задача.
Есть Юниты, у них задана координата x,y
У юнитов есть так же угол зрения = 60 градусов и направление взгляда, задано вектором, например (1,0) или (0.7, 0.7), дистанция взгляда равна 2(клеткам).Результатом работы программы должно быть: Что видит каждый юнит.
Просто не понимаю, куда копать и как реализовывать.

Что на  данный момент имею:

```
std::array<std::array<char, 30>, 30> map{};
```

Карта, где:

```
constexpr char empty_cell == 'e'// - пустая клетка 
constexpr char unit_cell == '*' //-  такая кледка говорит о том, что тут  находится 
наш юнит
```

```
template<typename T>
struct TransformComponent
{
    TransformComponent(T x, T y):x(x), y(y){};
    T x;
    T y;
};


class Unit
{
    public:
        Unit(TransformComponent<int> position, TransformComponent<float> direction, 
                                               std::string unit_title):position(position), 
                                               direction(direction),
                                               unit_title(unit_title){};
        TransformComponent<int> position;
        TransformComponent<float> direction;
        float vision_angle = 60;
        int distance_of_view = 2;
        std::string unit_title;

};
```

Как реализовать такую задачку в консоли? Подскажите ресурсы, информацию, что гуглить, пожалуйста.
Как я хочу решить задачу и с какими проблемами сталкиваюсь:
Сначала:

```
for(auto unit : units)
    { 
    //Бежим по всем существующим юнитам
    for (int i = 0; i<unit.vision_angle; i++) {
    //Бежим от 0 до нашего угла зрения
    /*Вот вопрос: Как преобразовать направление взгляда(1,0) в угол обзора?*/
    int nx = round(cos(deg)*unit.distance_of_view);
    int ny = round(sin(deg)*unit.distance_of_view);
    /*получаю точку на заданной дистанции с каждого угла*/
    if(map[ny][nx] == '*')
    {
        std::cout << unit.unit_title << "  See something\n";
    }
```

Comment: Наверное со школьного курса тригинометрии.

Comment: ну вообще то триг**о**нометрии, но да, даже так звучит уместно:)

Comment: Не понял, зона обзора в форме треугольника или сектора круга?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat сектора круга

Answer (score 0):

Раз поле зрения в виде сектора круга, то нужно проверить две вещи:

- расстояние между точками
- угол между вектором, соединяющим две точки, и направлением взгляда

Как проверять расстояние, надеюсь, понятно. Подсказка - корень считать медленно, лучше сравнивать квадраты.

Про угол - есть несколько вариантов. Чтобы не считать каждый раз синусы/косинусы/корни, я бы сделал так:

- Сделал две копии направления взгляда, и повернул их в разные стороны на половину угла обзора (умножением на [матрицу поворота 2х2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0), в одну сторону просто, а в другую - на ту же матрицу, но транспонированную).
- Взял векторные произведения между направлением на цель и этими двумя векторами. Раз векторное произведение всегда трехмерное, в исходных векторах считаем Z=0. У результата всегда будут X=0, Y=0, поэтому их не считаем, а считаем только Z.

  Дальше смотрим на знаки двух получившихся чисел - если одно больше нуля, а второе меньше, то цель входит в угол обзора (методом тыка подбираете, какое из чисел должно быть положительное, а какое отрицательное).